# How to Reload the JQGrid based on filter options?

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, jqgrid, struts2

I have a JQgrid, By default this will display all data's(say All, xxx, yyy, zzz). I have a filter drop-down, by default with "All" selected. If I change to xxx, it should call a function by passing "xxx" to call a struts action. Based on the action's return value  (JSON data) the jqgrid should populate again with the new data. As of now, It is calling "All" even I select "xxx". How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try out some thing like this. This function reloads your jqGrid.

> $("[#TableId]").jqGrid('GridUnload');

```
jQuery("[#TableId]").jqGrid({
    url: "........html",
    datatype: "json",
    jsonReader : {
        root : "rootObjlst",
        page : "page",
        total : "total",
        records : "records",
        repeatitems : false
    } ,
```